# Azure SQL Database - Optimise simple view

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database with a standard S2 SKU. I have a view that returns recently modified data from several large tables (10,000,000 records each) with infrequently changing data. Each of them has a [LastModified] column of type datetime2 with a non-clustered index. The following view takes several minutes to execute. Is there some way I could optimize it to run faster considering that there are rarely ever any recently modified entries?

```
SELECT 
      large1.[Col1],
      large3.[Col2],
      small.[Col3],
FROM     
         [LargeTable1] large1
   JOIN  [LargeTable2] large2 ON large1.ID = large2.large1ID
   JOIN  [LargeTable3] large3 ON large2.large3ID = large3.ID
   LEFT JOIN [SmallTable] small ON small.ID = large1.ID
WHERE 
         large1.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
   OR    large2.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
   OR    large3.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
   OR     small.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
```

I can modify the view or add indexes but the table structures are fixed. [LargeTable2] and [LargeTable3] have bigint primary keys but [LargeTable1] has a primary key of type nvarchar(13). [SmallTable] is dependent on [LargeTable1] and has a nvarchar(13) primary key which is also the foreign key. All of the primary keys have clustered indexes.

When I check the query's execution plan, I see it spends most of its time on the two joins to [LargeTable1].

Comment: If Col1, Col2, Col3 comes from the same table you can try to rewrite with a UNION ALL to eliminate the ORs

Comment: The results come from 3 of the 4 tables. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT 
      large1.[Col1],
      large3.[Col2],
      small.[Col3]
FROM     
         [LargeTable1] large1
   JOIN  [LargeTable2] large2 ON large1.ID = large2.large1ID
   JOIN  [LargeTable3] large3 ON large2.large3ID = large3.ID
   LEFT JOIN [SmallTable] small ON small.ID = large1.ID
WHERE 
         large1.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      large1.[Col1],
      large3.[Col2],
      small.[Col3]
FROM     
         [LargeTable1] large1
   JOIN  [LargeTable2] large2 ON large1.ID = large2.large1ID
   JOIN  [LargeTable3] large3 ON large2.large3ID = large3.ID
   LEFT JOIN [SmallTable] small ON small.ID = large1.ID
WHERE 
         large2.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      large1.[Col1],
      large3.[Col2],
      small.[Col3]
FROM     
         [LargeTable1] large1
   JOIN  [LargeTable2] large2 ON large1.ID = large2.large1ID
   JOIN  [LargeTable3] large3 ON large2.large3ID = large3.ID
   LEFT JOIN [SmallTable] small ON small.ID = large1.ID
WHERE 
         large3.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      large1.[Col1],
      large3.[Col2],
      small.[Col3]
FROM     
         [LargeTable1] large1
   JOIN  [LargeTable2] large2 ON large1.ID = large2.large1ID
   JOIN  [LargeTable3] large3 ON large2.large3ID = large3.ID
   LEFT JOIN [SmallTable] small ON small.ID = large1.ID
WHERE
         small.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
```

And create the adequate indexes.

Comment: Thanks. You're a star. It executes instantly now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a process for trying a few different things, as unfortunately, we cannot play with the data to work out what's going on.

Firstly, I suggest (for investigation/confirmation) doing a `SELECT ID FROM Large1 WHERE LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())` - and do it separately for all four tables. This assumes ID is the primary key.

Ensure each one uses the index on LastModified - each should ideally be close to instantaneous. If it has to read the whole table, or if the estimates are very different from the actuals, then something's gone wrong with your indexes (e.g., you have an index that has the LastModified column, but not as the first value).

If the above needed fixing and you fixed it, see if that fixes your overall problem.

<edit: Also potentially try updating statistics on the tables. In SQL Server, statistics may not be updated very frequently in a table that size, and therefore the estimates don't include the latest updates - which are exactly the ones you want - so it assumes a much smaller number than actually read. Research the 'Ascending key problem' for more info.>

A second question is whether the indexes are 'covering indexes' (e.g., include all the fields you need for the view - LastModified, ID, Col1, Col2, Col3 etc as appropriate).

If not, you can try making the indexes into covering indexes. You can check by the same process as above (selecting ID from each table with the WHERE clause) but instead of just ID, select all the relevant columns - and ensure it uses the index.

Note if you play with this index, it could slow down others' queries if they use this index - especially if you include big fields in the index (it will blow out the size of the index).

If this is being done in a stored procedure, another option (rather than covering indexes) is to create a temporary table first with all the IDs e.g., `CREATE TABLE #Ids (Id int PRIMARY KEY, Id_text nvarchar(13))` and then just run through each table putting the IDs into this table e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO #Ids (Id, Id_Text)
SELECT CAST(ID AS int), ID FROM Large1 WHERE large1.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION
SELECT ID, CAST(ID) AS nvarchar(13) FROM Large2 WHERE large2.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION
SELECT ID, CAST(ID) AS nvarchar(13) FROM Large3 WHERE large3.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
UNION
SELECT ID, CAST(ID) AS nvarchar(13) FROM Small1 WHERE large4.LastModified > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, getdate())
```

Once you have this table with IDs, do your select by joining the tables to this table as  appropriate (e.g., Large1 gets joined on the ID_text field)

Answer (score 0):

your problem of query being slow has everything to do with indexing. if you have 20000 record in smallTable and 2,000,000 records in largeTable1 without indexing it will scan 40billion rows to give you result but if you index the large table it will be reduced to 200,000 and if you index smallTable as well it will scan only 10,000 rows. So indexing all ID fields is the most critical part of your problem.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. All of the primary keys already have clustered indexes. I forgot to mention that before. I have updated the question.